# Transmit data over ssh using pythons pickle

Tags: ssh, python-3.x, pipe, pickle

I would like to send a unicode string through a pipe in ssh using pythons pickle and pipes:

```
import subprocess
import pickle

cmd=['ssh', 'user@host', '/usr/bin/env', 'python3', '-c', \
  '"import sys;import pickle;import os;os.mkdir(pickle.Unpickler(sys.stdin).load())"']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

pickler = pickle.Pickler(p.stdin)

pickler.dump('äöü')
```

This yields the following error:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also noticed that unicode characters sent to the subprocess are not displayed correctly, instead I only see their hexadecimal representation. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pickle wants binary files, and reads and writes bytes data, and while the stdin/stdout created for your process by `subprocess` are in binary mode, sys.stdin is in text mode.

By changing the target code to use `sys.stdin.buffer` the above code works correctly.

Comment: Well, p.stdout and p.stdin are of the type '_io.FileIO', so they have no buffer. sys.stdin.buffer does not work either...

Comment: @hfhc2: Aha, yes, the stdin/stdout from subprocess are indeed already in binary format (I didn't know that), but on the receiving side you are using sys.stdin, which isn't. :-) I updated the answer.

Comment: Substituting sys.stdin.buffer in the cmd does not work for me. I also tried sys.stdin.buffer.raw, which is of type _io.FileIO, but this does not work either...